# Why do I use interface properties like this?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

```
internal interface ICarrotModule
{
    string str { get; }
}
class Dataserver : ICarrotModule
{

    private string _Moudle = "Module Test";

    string ICarrotModule.str { get { return _Moudle; }
```

I just have to write a project. What is the meaning of A like that? What kind of call do you make?

Answer (score 2):

This is called explicit interface implementation. It is usually used when you are implementing two interfaces that contain a particular method or property signature. This method of implementation helps keep the two implementations separate.

[Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: Most importantly, an explicitly implemented member can only be accessed via a reference of the interface type. In your case, you would not be able to access the `str` property via a variable of type `Dataserver`. Instead, you'd have to cast as type `ICarrotModule`. You might do this in situations where a member will only be accessed via the interface, e.g. if you implemented `IList` and the only place that implementation would be used is when binding to a `DataGridView`, which will only ever access the object as that interface type.